# Printing side-by-side without a space character, inside for-loop in python

Tags: python

for this code in python,

```
>>>word="spaces"
>>>for i in range(len(word)):
...   print word[i],
...
s p a c e s
>>>
```

If I do not want any spaces in between the letters that are printed, what should I do ? In C for eg, the printing is by default next to the last printed character.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-in-python-without-newline-or-space

Answer (score 1):

Use `sys.stdout.write`:

```
>>> word = 'spaces'
>>> for c in word:
...     sys.stdout.write(c)
...
spaces>>>
```

Side note: As you can see above, you don't need to use indexes; Just iterate the string to get characters.